# Check serial number of Harddrive or SSD in Citrix netscaler?

Tags: citrix, adc, netscaler

Looking for some CLI commands in Netscaler shell to find serial number of SSD/HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, should have done it in Q&A style.

```
> shell
# smartctl -a /dev/ad8

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     STXXXXXXX0
Serial Number:    ABCWHATEVER
LU WWN Device Id: 01010101010
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Citrix ADC CLI command should also give you the serial number.

```
> show hardware
    Platform: **
    Manufactured on: **
    CPU: **
    Host Id: **
    Serial no: **
    Encoded serial no: **
    Netscaler UUID: **
```